# Yiibooster: TbExtendedGridView multiple extendedSummary

Tags: php, gridview, yii, yii-extensions

Is it possible to have two different extendedSummary in one TbExtendedGridView?

If yes could someone please guide how to acheive it.

Link to the Extension: [Yiibooster](http://yiibooster.clevertech.biz/extendedGridView#extendedsummary)

Thanks